# WordPress Custom Post Type Hierarchy

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

I use the custom post type "events". I make a custom page template `page-events.php`.

I make a page "Events" (slug `events`) as archive page.
Select "Events" as page template.

Nothing will show, but when I switch over to default page template insteed of "Events" everythings works fine.

**The WP body class shows `events-template-default single single-events`**

So, I don't really why?

My settings:

#### page-events.php

```
<?php 
/*
Template Name: Events
*/
?>
...


<?php               
$args = array(
    'post_type'              => array( 'events' ),
    'posts_per_page'         => '-1',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);              

$news_query = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $news_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while ( $news_query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php $news_query->the_post(); ?>

...

<?php endwhile; endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

#### functions.php

```
<?php 

// Register Custom Post Type "Events"
function cpt_events() {
    $labels = array(
        'name'                => _x( 'Events', 'Post Type General Name', 'theme_mmm' ),
        'singular_name'       => _x( 'Events', 'Post Type Singular Name', 'theme_mmm' ),
        'menu_name'           => __( 'Events', 'theme_mmm' ),
        'name_admin_bar'      => __( 'Events', 'theme_mmm' ),
        'parent_item_colon'   => __( 'Events:', 'theme_mmm' ),
        'all_items'           => __( 'Alle Events', 'theme_mmm' ),
        'add_new_item'        => __( 'Event hinzufügen', 'theme_mmm' ),
        'add_new'             => __( 'Event hinzufügen', 'theme_mmm' ),
        'new_item'            => __( 'Event hinzufügen', 'theme_mmm' ),
        'edit_item'           => __( 'Event bearbeiten', 'theme_mmm' ),
        'update_item'         => __( 'Aktualisieren', 'theme_mmm' ),
        'view_item'           => __( 'Events ansehen', 'theme_mmm' ),
        'search_items'        => __( 'Suchen', 'theme_mmm' ),
        'not_found'           => __( 'Keine Treffer', 'theme_mmm' ),
        'not_found_in_trash'  => __( 'Keine Treffer', 'theme_mmm' ),
    );

    $args = array(
        'label'               => __( 'Events', 'theme_mmm' ),
        'description'         => __( 'Beschreibung', 'theme_mmm' ),
        'labels'              => $labels,
        'supports'            => array( 'title', 'editor' ),
        'taxonomies'          => array(''),
        'hierarchical'        => false,
        'public'              => true,
        'show_ui'             => true,
        'show_in_menu'        => true,
        'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-calendar-alt',
        'menu_position'       => 5,
        'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
        'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
        'can_export'          => true,
        'has_archive'         => false,     
        'exclude_from_search' => false,
        'publicly_queryable'  => true,
        'rewrite'             => true,
        'capability_type'     => 'page',
    );
    register_post_type( 'events', $args );

}
add_action( 'init', 'cpt_events', 0 );

?>
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to Stack Overflow! How do you mean 'nothing will show'?
 Please provide your `page-events.php` template code so we can see what is in it. Also to create archives for a CPT can be done using the archive template hierarchy instead of needing to make a page in the dashboard and assign a template.

Comment: I added some code above. I thinks it's a hierarchy problem. **The WP body class shows events-template-default single single-events**.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make an archive page for your post type `events`, copy stock `archive.php` of your theme, rename it to `archive-events.php` and modify it from there to suit your needs.
If you're trying to make a template for a single page of `events` post type, copy stock `single` of your theme, rename it to `single-events.php` and modify it from there.
P.S. You've name your post type `events`. It's usually a good practice to use singular form instead of plural one, so `event` in your case

Refer to [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/files/2014/10/template-hierarchy.png) image to see how Wordpress selects correct template and [this](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) page for hierarchy related information.

Comment: Thank you, you're right. I did this, too. But I didn't works. I prefere to use a custom template page to echo the cpt archive page instead of archive-CPT-.php. I can set up the page better (with GUI) for SEO and select the page into the wp menu without additional settings for customer.

Comment: @ingozoell I just noticed you set `has_archive` to `false so yeah, `archive-events.php` wouldn't work. These 3 dots in your `page-events.php template` is there an actual code instead of them to output anything?

Comment: Just `the_title()` and `the_content()`. But I wonder more about the css body classes: `events-template-default single single-events` Single, why?

Comment: @ingozoell `single` because it is in fact a single page, `single-events` is because it's a single page with a slug `events`. Does your query return any results and it's a problem with display or it doesn't return anything at all?

Comment: Hm, but why it will not use the existing `single-events.php` template for displaying?

Comment: @ingozoell because `single-events.php` is template for a singple page of `events` post type